# Read Time Out Android Studio downloading gradle builder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working with Android Studio on a restricted network. I have a new project with an empty activity but it doesn't build and it's the first project.

When I downloaded Android, I had to add the certs of google and jetbrain, because the network, and that worked, but when it started to build it and download all files of classpath, says the error "Read Time Out"  it is because it cannot downloaded builder.jar from google repository, It's weird because all the other files downloaded good but whit this one is the error!

I've tried to reinstall Android Studio and it doesn't work, I've tried to create a new project and it doesn't work too, I don't know what could be... I thought it was the speed connection, but when I put the URL ('https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.3/builder-3.1.3.jar') in navigator it starts to download.

Android Studio Version: 3.1.3

[This is my build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noS9L.png)

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0tek.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the speed connection, so I downloaded from the URL and I put them in  .gradle folder, (I have to search the exact location) and it works. :D